# I am having a bit of trouble with my stacked bar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I am having trouble with plotting my chart. specifically the "bottom" section as in the output it shows only the red and yellow. the error message shows:
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
ax[1].bar(x, C, color = 'red', label='', zorder=2)

ax[1].bar(x, T, color = 'yellow', bottom = C , label='', zorder=2)

ax[1].bar(x, R, color = 'blue', bottom = C+T, label='', zorder=2)

ax[1].bar(x, S, color = 'green', bottom = C+T+R, label='', zorder=2)
```

It seems like when i try to put my T, R, S in the chart on top of the C, it won't want to cooperate

Comment: For this to work, `C`, `T`, `R` and `S` should be numerical 1D numpy arrays of the same length.  How are they created?

Comment: C = [37, 18, 19, 26, 8]
T = [12, 5, 8, 2, 5]
R = [12, 11, 2, 0, 1]
S = [2, 6, 1, 2, 0]
x = np.arange(5)

Comment: i created it like that

Comment: So you need `C = np.array(C)`, similar for the 3 other lists.  Note that for lists `+` means concatenating them, while for numpy arrays `+` means summing corresponding elements. For lists, `C + T` is `[37, 18, 19, 26, 8, 12, 5, 8, 2, 5] `.

Comment: AHH okay, that makes more sense. Thank you so much for the help! :)